# How do i locate this webelement in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

My problem is locating a checkbox element on my webpage. I'm using Selenium webdriver with Eclipse, TestNG and Java as chosen language.

Inspecting the checkbox element gives me the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-privid="13" data-priviligeeid="406">
```

I've tried using the following xpath code, where the string is the xpath copied from the element in Chrome browser. I added the escape chararacters for the quotation marks to be accepted:

```
WebElement ChangeButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("[@id=\"privs\"]/div[1]/div[2]/label/input"));
```

But doing this leaves ChangeButton empty.

I also tried looping through an array until i find a specifik data-privid value:

```
ArrayList<WebElement> inputs  =(ArrayList<WebElement>)driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));     

      if(inputs != null) {

          for(WebElement checkbox : inputs) {
              String attribute = checkbox.getAttribute("data-privid");
              System.out.println(attribute);

              ....
}
}
```

This did not work either, as attribute never gets any values.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

EDIT: This has been solved!

The reason your solutions didn't work for me at first, was because I had navigation in methods belonging to one class, and the web element grabbing in a second class. I tried to combine them in an `xml` file, but for some reason I ended up on the wrong `url` when the locator class tried to do its thing. Thank you everyone for providing answers. I went with the `css` locators and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use XPath. CSS selectors are more handy. Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox'][data-privid='13']"));
```

Comment: This seems VERY convenient. Unfortunately I can't get it to work yet (I still can't reach the element properties), but I will definately explore this path. I too would prefer not using xpath due to how fragile my tests would be. Thank you Kim!

Comment: You can express the same thing in XPath: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'][@data-privid='13']"));`. It's almost the same, but there are more `/` and `@` characters in it. Especially when you deal with multiple class attributes, XPath can be a real pain in the #$&§ compared to CSS selectors. The only case I can think of where XPath is better than CSS is when you want to adress textcontent inside an HTML tag, which cannot be done with Selenium's rather simple CSS implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try below XPath

```
//input[@type='checkbox' and @data-privid='13']
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I still can't get it to work, but your answer reminds of Kim's so it's given me some help anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your xpaht expression `"[@id=\"privs\"]/div[1]/div[2]/label/input"` **is not valid**.
Seems you try to find at first step  a element with `id="privs"` this would be: `"*[@id='privs']"` or (better if this element is a div)  `"div[@id='privs']"`

Then your xpath may look like this:

`"div[@id='privs']/div[1]/div[2]/label/input"`

Comment: Ah, many thanks! Yes, I thought it looked weird to try to cram the quote marks in there. I tried your xpath code but it unfortunately still doesn't work. I'm thinking there must be something else missing, maybe I need to pause the test run for a while after reaching the page and before looking for elements? I'm very new to automated test writing. I've realized I probably want to avoid using xpath due to fragility, but it will be good to get it to work for when I have to. :)